# overlay/overriding v/s extending of components in AEM

Tags: aem

What is the difference between extending a component and overlaying a component. Can someone please explain with developer point of view.

Comment: you can find some more information at this [adobe thread](http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__fiiv-am_trying_tounderst.html)

Comment: In easy words, extending is like get the complete OOTB component under /apps from /libs, overlaying is like get what file is required to change in component according to requirement. hope it clears, if not refer AEM Documentation. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Overlay Component:**

*Creating a custom component by copying a foundation component to your project and modifying it based on the need. 
For example you copy image component from **“/libs/foundation/components/image”** to your site folder **“/apps/testsite/components”** by doing so you are creating a new component with is exactly same as Image component. 
After copying you can make changes to component based on your requirements. But the problem with this approach would be that if you are upgrading CQ then new version of CQ might have new implementation of **“/libs/foundation/components/image”** component than those changes will not be reflected in your **“/apps/testsite/components/image”** component, 
so you have to manually make those changes in custom component.*

**Extend/Override Component:**

*Creating a custom component manually by creating all necessary nodes and setting value of **“sling:resourceSuperType”** property as **“/libs/foundation/components/image”**. By doing this you inherit all the feature of image component, even after upgrade you still inherit the features of image component.*